# Cannot copy file to another computer with Group Policy

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I created the GPO and wanted to copy files to another computer. 
**(Computer Configuration > Preferences > Windows setting >Files)**

The file is located on the server and shared.
[The folder security permission details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/352QO.png)

```
Action: Update
Source File: \\servername\test\copyfile.txt
Destination File: C:\test\copyfile.txt
```

Expected the file is copied,but there no file is copied.
The log is shown successful.

I searched this issue on Google and tried to follow their solutions but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do domain computers (because you are using a computer configuration) have access to read that share? If the share is set to only allow user accounts, then the computer object can't read your file.